# El password_verify siempre me rotarna false

Tags: php, mvc, php7

Estoy intentando hacer un login en el que obviamente tengo la password encriptada con la funcion password_hash y creo que lo hace correctamente, pero al verificar la password con la funcion password_verify siempre me devuelve falso y no puedo loguearme, lo raro es que antes estaba funcionando bien y ahora al querer hacer pruebas ya no funciono
Les dejo la funcion para el registro y la funcion para el loguin.

Registro.

```
public function save(){
    $opciones = array(
        'cost' => 12
    );
    $password_hashed = password_hash($this->getPass(), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(NULL, '{$this->getNombre()}', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '{$this->getCorreo()}', '{$this->getUser()}', '$password_hashed', NULL);";
    $save = $this->db->query($sql);
    
    $result = false;
    if($save){
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Login

```
public function logueo($password, $email){
    $result = false;
    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, pass FROM clientes WHERE correo = '$email'";
    $login = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($login && $login->num_rows == 1){
        $cliente = $login->fetch_object();
        
        if(password_verify($password, $cliente->pass)){
            $result = $cliente;
        }
        
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Estoy haciendo este proyecto con PHP MVC y es php 7.
No se que es lo que esta mal, pues hago las pruebas y uso la misma contraseña simpre y nada mas no funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar un ejemplo de `$password` y lo que obtienes en `$cliente` dentro de la función logueo?

Comment: ¿Verificaste que el registro existe en la tabla (`save()` retorna `true`)? ¿Verificaste que la consulta trae datos en el `SELECT`? ¿De qué tipo es la columna `pass` en `clientes`?

Comment: Verificaste que tu query no retorne mas de un resultado, no se como tengas tu base de datos, pero si llegas a tener dos usuarios con el mismo correo, te retornara mas de una fila y dará siempre false.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc como contraseña para pruebas siempre uso "1234" y lo que obtengo en $cliente es aún array con el id, nombre y password según coincida con el email

Comment: @A. Cedano si, el registro existe pues la función save() funciona correctamente, el SELECT si trae datos puesto que antes de añadirla al código siempre verifico la consulta en la base de datos y también al intentar debbuguear si me trae datos la consulta y la columna pasa es de tipo varchar(100)

Comment: @DarkFrost si, mi quiery solo retorna una resultado ya que la columna correo es una llave única y en la misma función logueo conforma que solo retorne un renglon

Comment: Si haces un var_dump ¿que es lo que tienes en login?

Comment: Cree un array para saber que me dévolvia y me regresa y lo imprimí con var_dump, login tiene los datos correctos del resultado dela consulta, también imprimo el renglón de la tabla y está bien y el resultado del password_verify y siempre es false

Comment: Puedes añadir la salida del var_dump a la pregunta